# DataTrigger does not change Text property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I'm attempting to use a data-trigger on a style to change a property.

In compliance with the "[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" requirements...

To reproduce, first create a WPF application in Visual Studio.

Within the App.xaml.cs :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Foo{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private bool _clicked;
        public bool Clicked {
            get { return this._clicked; }
            set {
                this._clicked = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Clicked" ) );
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Within the MainWindow.xaml :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <lib:Boolean x:Key="True">True</lib:Boolean>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Click="button_Click">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Text="Unclicked">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                        Binding="{Binding
                                            Clicked,
                                            Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
                                            Value="{StaticResource True}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Clicked" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Within the MainWindow.xaml.cs -

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Foo{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow( ) {
            InitializeComponent( );
        }

        private void button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
            ( Application.Current as App ).Clicked = !( Application.Current as App ).Clicked;
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note - I tried setting the value of the data trigger to just `"True"`, and that also did not work ( the trigger did not catch, and text did not change based on setting the property to a new value ).

So why is the data-trigger not catching or working here? ( Either with the static resource or the literal value )? Even more relevant - why am I getting this error? The "After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified" error? And what is the proper method of accomplishing what I am trying to do here? ( Preferably still using a data-trigger and not a converter, since I do need to switch between two values ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *local value* assigned to the TextBlock's Text property has higher precedence than the value provided by the Setter in the DataTrigger. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for details.

Set the initial Text value by another Setter:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Unclicked"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Clicked,
                                       Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
                             Value="{StaticResource True}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Clicked" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

The error message you see when you use the Boolean resource is just the XAML designer complaining. There is no error at runtime.

Comment: So a value set by a literal ( as opposed to, say, a binding ) will supersede and invalidate a value set by a setter ( or a data trigger setter ), which is what was causing my error?

Comment: Exactly, see the linked MSDN article for details.

Comment: Thanks.

I don't have time to test right now but I will tomorrow and if it works I will mark your answer correct.