# DataTrigger when bound to a StaticResourse after setting the Source to Application Current dosen't work

Tags: wpf, xaml

Firstly I refered to the following post before posting [DataTrigger with value set to a static resource gives error - “After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381133/datatrigger-with-value-set-to-a-static-resource-gives-error-after-a-datatrig)

I am doing the same thing as posted here in my xaml. At the compile time I see a scribble with the error “After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified”. But when I run the app, the DataTrigger dosen't seem to be working. But just to test, instead of the StaticResource I hard code the value to a string it works fine. Please help.

```
<TextBlock
            Grid.Column="2"
            Text="{Binding DataContext.CurrentStatus,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style
                    TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockLightTextStyle}">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{StaticResource HeaderButtonBackgroundBrush}"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus,Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
                            Value="{StaticResource CartridgeNotLoaded}">
                            <Setter
                                Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you tried changing `Value="{Staticresource CartridgeNotLoaded}"` and got it to work correctly? Or, you tried changing `Source={x:Static Application.Current}` and got it to work correctly?

Comment: Ya i tried removing the source part from the xaml and said value="Cartridge not loaded"string and it worked fine.

Comment: Please see my answer below, I updated to include another possible solution to look into based on your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create your `CurrentStatus` (what your binding is trying to bind to)? Your binding may not be able to find CurrentStatus if it is not defined in the correct spot.

Try changing from:

```
Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus,Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
```

to:

```
Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

**Updated:**
Did you define your `CartridgeNotLoaded` resource in your xaml class? In order for `Value="{StaticResource CartridgeNotLoaded}"` to work it will have to use the resource itself. So, for example, you might have at the beginning of your xaml something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <(type goes here) x:Key="CartridgeNotLoaded"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Ya let me try like that. I have a resource dictionary file where i have that string and it's being initially called in app.xaml. that's where the resource is defined. Just like in my xaml StaticResource TextblockLightTextStyle is being called automatically.