# Wpf : Data Trigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datatrigger

this is my code and plz tell me why it is not working for me..

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Margin="10 0 0 0" Background="{DynamicResource Info}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Name="lblOrderType" Content="{Binding ordertype}" FontSize="15">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ordertype}" Value="Delivery">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382063/1136211

Comment: @dsdel thanks for quick response. You can see the content property of the Lable also bound to the same property and working perfectly .

Comment: Have you understood what dependency property value precedence is and how it affects your XAML?

Comment: @Clemens no... plz tell me about that, I am new in WPF

Comment: Clemens and tabby are right, by setting the Background explicit as an Attribute in your label definition - you cannot change it anymore with the DataTrigger. Remove the Background from the Label and the Trigger should work. You can set the Background by another setter as in: <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label"><Setter Property="Background" Value"{DynamicResource Info}" /> (As in described in the other links)

Comment: Please read the linked documentation and StackOverflow answer

Comment: The question should be closed as duplicate of e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44381133/1136211). Unfortunately I have already close-voted for another reason.

Comment: @dsdel thanks buddy. It works for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTrigger with value set to a static resource gives error - "After a 'DataTrigger' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381133/datatrigger-with-value-set-to-a-static-resource-gives-error-after-a-datatrig)