# DataGrid Select All functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wonder what I am doing wrong here. I have a DataGrid with one column called **Selected**. Next to it I have a **CheckBox** in a **DataGridTemplateColumn** which is also bound to the field  **"Selected"**. The idea is whenever the Checkbox is  checked or unchecked the selected field should  show **1**  or **0** respectively (i.e. Boolean values). This works fine.

However, I want also to place another CheckBox in the **Header** section of the DataGridTemplateColumn so that I am able to check or unckeck  all checkboxes in the **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate** section. This is where I am having issues in that, while the checkboxes in the **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate** section get checked or unchecked the corresponding values in the Selected Field do not get changed at all. It is as if the binding fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the simple XAML and the code behind for loading data into the **Selected** field.

```
<Grid>
 <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Selected}" Header="Selected"  />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Content=" Slect All" x:Name="headerCheckBox" />
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox x:Name="Mychk" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
              <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=headerCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                   <Setter TargetName="Mychk" Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
             </DataTemplate.Triggers>
           </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

VB.Net

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
 Dim MyTable = New System.Data.DataTable
 MyTable.Columns.Add("Selected", GetType(Integer))
 For Each array As Object In New List(Of Integer)() From {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   MyTable.Rows.Add(array)
 Next
 MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyTable.DefaultView
End Sub
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
            {
                System.Data.DataTable MyTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                MyTable.Columns.Add("Selected", typeof(int));
                foreach (object array in new List<int> {0,0,0,0,0})
                {
                    MyTable.Rows.Add(array);
                }
                MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyTable.DefaultView;
            }
         }
    }
```

**By the way I am trying to do everything in XAML without code behind (no converter either)**

Comment: You could probably use a MultiBinding for the Mychk.IsChecked property. The MultiBinding would contain the current Binding plus the one from the DataTrigger, and a multi-value converter would create the expected result.

Comment: That said, your problem is certainly [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382063/1136211). Move the IsChecked Binding to a Style Setter.

Comment: Hie Clemens, I have followed the link provided and made the following changes to CheckBox inside the CellTemplate  <CheckBox x:Name="Mychk" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                <CheckBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </CheckBox.Style>
                            </CheckBox>. Still it does not work

Comment: The thing is that I can do it in code behind. I really wanted to avoid code behind including Value Converter. Perhaps you can try it and post a working solution