# XAML DataTrigger Not Firing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property in my `ModularClientModule` class called `ExistsOnDisk`. When that property is set to false, I want to disable the CheckBox. For some reason, this does not seem to work despite me putting it last in the Triggers XAML block, which means it should be the last thing to fire. I.e, nothing should be interfering. **I know my code-behind should be correct because as you will see below, I have another control which receives the update and fires fine.**

This one here responds to the ExistsOnDisk property change without issue, and strikesthrough the text:

```
GridViewColumn x:Name="FileNameHeader" Header="File Name">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ModularClientModuleUI}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Filename}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExistsOnDisk}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

This one here does not, and the checkbox remains enabled:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="StatusHeader" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ModularClientModuleUI}">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox x:Name="ClientModuleStatusCheckBox" Margin="5, 0" Click="ClientModuleStatusCheckBox_Click" IsEnabled ="{Binding Client.Online}">
                    <CheckBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.CheckBox}">

                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Loaded">
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Unloaded">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Loading">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExistsOnDisk}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExistsOnDisk}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </CheckBox.Style>
                </CheckBox>
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: The IsEnabled Binding sets a local value of the IsEnabled property, which has higher precedence than the DataTrigger Setter values, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382063/1136211. There should generally only be a single Binding or Trigger that sets a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default value of the `IsEnabled` using a `Setter` and remove `IsEnabled ="{Binding Client.Online}"` from the `<CheckBox>` element:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ClientModuleStatusCheckBox" Margin="5, 0" Click="ClientModuleStatusCheckBox_Click">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.CheckBox}">

            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Loaded">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Unloaded">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadState}" Value="Loading">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExistsOnDisk}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Also note that you shouldn't use more than one trigger on the same `bool` property.

Comment: Ugh, the issue I have is that the conditions in which the CheckBox should be enabled are if the client is online AND either the LoadState is set to true or ExistsOnDisk is true. Otherwise, it should be disabled. I originally had a property in the ModularClientModuleUI structure that checked all of this at once and returned a bool, but I wanted to move it directly into the XAML because if I had a property dedicated for every condition that makes the cs code look really ugly. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Keep the property in the view model and return true or false from this based on your logic. XAML is a *markup* language. Keep your logic in the view models. This is not really related to the question you have actually posted though...